# memory leak after clearing vector of shared pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I have a vector of shared pointer like this:

```
vector <shared_ptr<PhotoWidget>> photoWidgets;
PhotoWidget *photoWidget = new PhotoWidget;
photoWidget->setup(widget);
photoWidgets.emplace_back(move(photoWidget));
```

I need to clear the memory , but I can't find the proper way for doing that, I read similar topics but noting works for me, I used this code so far without any success.

```
for( auto&& widget : photoWidgets ) {
    widget.reset();
}
vector<shared_ptr<PhotoWidget>>().swap(photoWidgets);
photoWidgets.clear();
photoWidgets.shrink_to_fit();
```

the PhotoWidget class is:

```
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "baseWidget.h"
#include "../lib/json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

class PhotoWidget: public BaseWidget {
public:
    void setup(json config);
    void update();
    void draw();
    void loadNewPhoto(json data);
    void loadDefaultPhoto();

    ofImage image;
    bool defaultPhotoRunning = true;
    uint64_t lastElapsedTimeMillis;
    uint64_t interval;
};
```

Comment: How did you determine you had a memory leak?

Comment: As a side note - the point of smart pointers is to *not* free the memory yourself.

Comment: @juanchopanza with top command in linux, I have an outside trigger for clearing and refilling the vector and when I use the trigger I can see the memory of app increased in an unacceptable amount

Comment: @nim4n That isn't necessarily checking for memory *leaks*. It just means the runtime hasn't given back all the memory htat has been freed by the program.

Comment: But it would help if you posted a [mcve].

Comment: @juanchopanza what is the proper way? I have two template in my UI and I change them with and outside trigger so every time I switch between the templates the memory usage increased and I'm some how sure It is related to this vectors because all of my UI widget are in this vectors.

Comment: You could use a dedicated tool such as valgrind to tell you if you have memory leaks.

Comment: Instances of PhotoWidget shouldn't leak in a code like this. Maybe there are some allocations inside PhotoWidget which are leaked when widget is destructed.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin I edited my original question for definition of PhotoWidget, Should I remove the object inside of the class manually?

Comment: @juanchopanza I checked with valgrind and It confirm the memory leak.

Comment: Normally, when you call reset, it will be deleted according to the [shared_ptr doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).
Maybe it's a fake positive.

Comment: Better to avoid raw new and call directly `std::make_shared`. As a side note, moving raw-pointer is useless.

Comment: @Jarod42  I need to create an object that is not copyable and put It after the process in the vector,  vector of shared object was the best way I found for moving my current object to a vector, is there a better way?

Comment: I meant, instead of `PhotoWidget *photoWidget = new PhotoWidget;` use `std::shared_ptr<PhotoWidget> photoWidget = std::make_shared<PhotoWidget>();`. By avoiding raw new, you should avoid memory leak easier.

Comment: @nim4n Do you store this `shared_ptr` anywhere else? One common issue with reference counted pointers is circular dependencies. Make sure you don't have any.

Comment: @Jarod42 I used your code but the problem is the same.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko No I just create theme as I wrote and move them to the vector.

Comment: @nim4n Check reference count before you reset pointers in `photoWidgets`. If all pointers have only one reference, then they can't leak. And [MCVE] will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I change this part:

```
PhotoWidget *photoWidget = new PhotoWidget;
photoWidget->setup(widget);
photoWidgets.emplace_back(move(photoWidget));
```

to this, and the problem is solved:

```
photoWidgets.emplace_back(make_shared<PhotoWidget>());
photoWidgets[widget["ID"]]->setup(widget);
```

It seems some how creating  new pointer in a variable doesn't worked properly in this case.

Comment: Why do you use move and not just photoWidgets.push_back(make_shared<PhotoWidget>());